# What is the time complexity of this frequency counting sort algorithm?

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
def f(array, mn, mx):
    count_freq = [0] * (mx - mn + 1) # to store frequency


    for i in array:
        count_freq[i] += 1 # populate frequency


    result = [] # to be returned

    for i in range(mn, mx +1):
        result += [i] * count_freq[i]

    return result
```

When f([1, 4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1], 0, 7) is called, this is the output [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7]
Where MX is the maximum and MN is the minimum number in the array so therefore is the time complexity O(N)?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your code is O(N + K) where N is the number of elements and K is the range of your numbers [min, max]. This is because you'll loop over every number i in the range (K) + for each number i, you'll add `count_freq[i]` elements to the result. summing all the numbers in `count_freq`, you'll get N which is the number of elements.